# bash script to retrieve list of Rest api services from various datapower boxes and display the content to a browser or excel sheet

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have a rest mgmt uri. using that I have to pull the list of services from various datapower boxes. 
For every environment I have one datapower box and one rest mgmt uri.
So I have to pull the details from every datapower box for every environment and display all the content in an organized readable format either to browser or excel sheet.

I need to use only bash scripting. 
as no other type of scripts will work in my system.

I have used curl to pull the details but I was able to pull only for one rest mgmt api.

```
curl -k -u 'username:password' https://dpbox001:5554/mgmt/status/DEV/ObjectStatus
```

I was able to get the details but was not able to display in readable form and that to in the similar way for all the dpboxes for all environments.

Output I got after running the above curl command :

```
"Class" : "ExampleProtocolHandler",
"OpState" : "up",
"AdminState" : "enabled",
"Name" : "Example_service",
"EventCode" : "0x00000000",
"ErrorCode" : "",
"ConfigState" : "saved"}, {
```

the below was the restmgmt uri

```
https://dpbox001:5554/mgmt/status/DEV/ObjectStatus
```

1. I need to get the details using the rest mgmt uri (https://dpbox001:5554/mgmt/status/DEV/ObjectStatus) for all the dpboxes(total they are 20) for all environments. (I have TST, STG, PRD).
2. After gathering the above details I need to display the complete information in structured form either to browser or excel sheet like below

   Output in one single line like below to be displayed either to console or browser

   class : Exampleprotocohandler     Opstate : up        Adminstate: enabled       Name: Exampleservice    Eventcode: 0x0000000   Errorcode :      configstate: saved

   or else output to excel sheet like below columns and rows format

   class    opstate    Adminstate   Name    Eventcode     ErrorCode   configstate 
   Example    up        Enabled     service  0xx000        if any       saved

Comment: SO is not for coding or other work requests. You need to do this yourself, and then come back when you have a detailed issue where you're stuck.

Comment: `while read dpbox ; do curl ....http://${dpbox}... | formatData.awk > reports/$dpbox.rpt ; done < dpBoxList.txt` is a bare-bones structure that will support the problem as you describe it above. read the [awk tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) and focus particularly on using `printf` to create output format. But no, we can't do this for you. Good luck.